# moving paddles only pushing the puck, not hitting it

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am trying to move the paddle, if it hits the puck, the puck should move away. But the puck only move, more like the paddle is only pushing it.

Declaring paddle:

```
p1.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
p1.name = p1Name
p1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 30)
p1.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0
p1.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0
p1.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
p1.physicsBody.dynamic = true
p1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = p1Category
p1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | pCategory
p1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = pCategory

p1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/4)
self.addChild(p1)
```

Delcaring puck:

```
puck.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
puck.name = pName
puck.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
puck.physicsBody.restitution = 0.8
puck.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.5
puck.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.5
puck.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
puck.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
puck.physicsBody.friction = 0.0
puck.physicsBody.dynamic = true
puck.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = pCategory
puck.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | p1Category
puck.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = p1Category

puck.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2)
self.addChild(puck)
```

How i move the paddle:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let body: SKPhysicsBody = self.nodeAtPoint(location).physicsBody
        if (body.node.name == self.p1Name) {
            self.fingerOnP1 = true
            self.p1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
        let body = self.nodeAtPoint(location).physicsBody
        if (body != nil && body.node != nil) {
            if (body.node.name == self.p1Name && self.fingerOnP1 == true) {
                let paddle = self.childNodeWithName(p1Name) as SKShapeNode

                var paddleX: Int = Int(paddle.position.x) + Int(location.x - previousLocation.x)
                let _x: Int = Int(paddle.frame.width/2)
                paddleX = max(paddleX, _x)
                paddleX = min(paddleX, Int(self.size.width)-_x)

                var paddleY: Int = Int(paddle.position.y) + Int(location.y - previousLocation.y)
                let _y: Int = Int(paddle.frame.height/2)
                paddleY = max(paddleY, _y)
                paddleY = min(paddleY, Int(self.size.height)-_y)

                paddle.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(paddleX), CGFloat(paddleY))
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var onP1 = false
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if (self.nodeAtPoint(location) == p1) {
            onP1 = true
        }
    }

    if (onP1 == true) {
        self.fingerOnP1 == false
        self.p1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | pCategory
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is I'm not applying any force to the paddle, I'm just moving the paddle, too. How would I apply force while moving it?

I thought of apply impulse to the puck after contact, but i have no idea how to move it a proper angle or make it move at a proper speed.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody!
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody!

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask > contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == p1Category && secondBody.categoryBitMask == pCategory) {
        if (self.fingerOnP1) {
            NSLog("hit", nil)
            secondBody.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(20, 0))
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Reduce the puck's linear damping and angular damping, it should help

Comment: Nope not helping at all

Comment: Try setting the friction property to zero

Comment: Nothing changes, except that the ball speed up a little

Comment: So you want an impusle of a higher intensity to be applied to the puck? Just for reference, this is supposed to be a Air Hockey simulation, right?

Comment: Yeah, my own current solution is to apply impulse after contact

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest, to calculate and apply impulse in the didBeginContact method. If you are still not satisfied with that, post the code, and we can see how it can be made better

Comment: Set your MASS property of the physicsbodies.  (paddle being way larger)